# Why does this program allocate 8 pages but can only fit in 2048 nodes whose size is 8 bytes?

Tags: c, operating-system, system, xv6

A node is defined as follows:

```
    struct node {
      int value;
      struct node *next;
    };
```

By using `sizeof(struct node)` I learn that a node is 8 bytes(in xv6). So I use `malloc` to allocated some memory space to store some nodes. A single page in xv6 is 4096 bytes, if I have 8 pages, I can store 4096 such nodes. However, that's not what is happening, after I `malloc` 2048 such nodes, if I `malloc` another one, more pages are allocated for the current process, why is that?

```
    // Now display how many pages are allocated to the process
    // Suppose there is a system call named memcount(), it is given by
    // my professor, I wouldn't think there's any problem with that
    //
    memcount(); // which prints 3, meaning that initially, without
                // allocaing anything, 3 pages = 12288 bytes of memory allocated

    for(i = 0; i < 2048; ++i) {
      struct node *nd = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    }

    memcount(); // which prints 11, so 8 more pages are allocated

    // If we allocated 1 more node
    struct node *nd = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    memcount(); // which prints 19, another 8 pages are allocated
```

That's where I am so confused, shouldn't there be a lot space left in the first 8 pages? Since the size of a single node is only 8 bytes, why are there more pages allocated to the process?

Comment: `malloc(X)` uses more than `X` bytes of memory. Some memory is stealthly allocated for the heap control structures.

Comment: Generally when you allocate a small amount of memory, you may actually reserve more than you specified (the system might have a minimum size it will allocate, or insist on a power of two allocation size, or some other such thing).  There also may be additional overhead to keep details of the allocated block, which will use space outside the part you asked for.

Comment: @Dmitri, Thank you. I understand that `malloc(n)` uses a little bit more than `n` bytes, but that should be a little right? how come that happens? I edited the post, I think that explains it more clearly

Comment: @DYZ, Thank you, I understand that malloc(n) uses a little bit more than n bytes, but that should be a little right? how come that happens? I edited the post, I think that explains it more clearly

Comment: Google "simple C heap allocator" for very basic malloc() implementations.

Comment: Your struct only uses "a little bit" of space... the extra per-allocation data could easily be enough to make the actual space used by each allocation twice as big as your structure, which would require 8 pages instead of 4.  If you're concerned about it, you could allocate arrays of structures instead of allocating them individually, which should reduce the overhead.

Comment: `n+8` is "a little more than `n`" if `n` is 124. Is it still "a little more than `n`" if `n` is 8? The malloc overhead is a fixed size, regardless of the amount allocated. Typically it contains the size of the allocated block plus some padding, so 8 bytes is plausible.

Comment: @Dmitri, Thank you, that explains a lot, thank you again

Comment: @rici, Thank you, it is much more clear now, thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was already answered in the Comment: `malloc()` need some space to store, how the Memory is used.

The memoryhandler see the heap as a single large array of bytes (because the RAM is one big array in the most memory models). (There are also other memory models or the memorymanager maybe store some data in extra pages, but to make it simple, we ignore such cases)

As an example, we could think of system, where the first 4 bytes used as pointer (`p0`), where the next valid blocks start and the next 4 bytes for a variable (`size_t`, `s0`) how many bytes is used for this block (we need 2 variables to detect when a block between 2 blocks is freed). The next block also have a pointer (`p1`) to next (the next of the next) block and a variable for the size of the block (`s1`)

After this header are the data which you can use, `malloc()` return a pointer to the first byte after this header. The variable `s0` will store how many bytes you requested. After a new `malloc()`, a new header will be created after the first block, and the p0 will point to this header:

```
Address:   0x10    0x14    0x18    0x1B    0x20    0x24    0x28 ...
Name:      p0      s0      value   next    p1      s1      value...
Value:     0x20    8       ??      0x28    0       8       ??
```

Here is the situation after you alloc 2 blocks, `p1` and `s1` are variables for the header of the second block. You can only use the variable `next` and `value`. The Pointer which `malloc()` returned are `0x18` and `0x28`.

To avoid using half of the space for the memoryhandler, you could alloc a larger array in one step. You could use a `struct` like this:

```
struct Node_T
  {
    int values[512];
    size_t usedValues;  
    struct Node_T *next;
  }
```

Then you would need 4*4 = 16 Bytes total overhead (including the overhead of the memoryhandler, and assumed the memoryhandler need 8 bytes header per block and `int`, pointers and `size_t` are 4 bytes). But you need extra copy or move overhead when you remove or add a value between other values.